# Jmeter - weighted random values?

Tags: java, testing, jmeter

How can I go about running tests/controllers based on random weight? For instance, have two tests, one with a weight of 25%, the other with 50%. The one with 50 should run twice as often.

Perhaps throughput controller mixed with random somehow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can use Throughput Controllers configured someway like the following:

[image: Throughput Controller]

Throughput values are pre-set, either from configuration properties or generated in acceptable range of values (0..100 in this case).

Answer (score 1):

For some simple weightings you can use the fact the switch controller defaults to the first child to your advantage. Eg 50% 25% 25% like so

```
Switch Controller - ${__Random(0,3)}
 - Child 0 (and 3)
 - Child 1
 - Child 2
```

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random

You take this one step further by grouping tasks in Random and Simple controllers as the children.

Answer (score 0):

You better use 2 thread groups for this case. 
Set up first to generate more request than second.

PS. You may use Throughput Shaping Timer to control rate in each group.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by creating a Switch Controller with the following switch value:

```
${__javaScript( var s="001"; new Number(s.charAt( Math.floor(Math.random()*s.length) )) )}
```

The javascript selects a random character from the string `s` and converts it to a number. So in the example above, 0 would be selected twice as often as 1, and the weightings can be altered by adding/removing characters from the string.

I used a String and not an Array was because the javascript version used by my version of JMeter appeared to not support array literals, so this made it a bit less verbose.