# How can i partition the threads by their percent

Tags: testing, jmeter

I wanna slice the threads by their percent. For example :

> **- My Test Plan**
>
> *-SignUp Thread (this task should be %10)*
>
> *-LogIn Thread  (this task should be %40)*
>
> *-Search Thread (this task should be %30)*
>
> *-Add New Topic (this task should be %20)*

How can i do this partition ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can possibly use set of [Throughput Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) - but they will work properly only in loop (as "children" of Loop Controller e.g.).

Look into these for details:

- [Purpose of Throughput Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379033/purpose-of-throughput-controller)
- [Jmeter - weighted random values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481867/jmeter-weighted-random-values)
- [How throughput controller work?](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/How-throughput-controller-work-td3328412.html)

Comment: Hey Alies, thanks for answer. Can throughput Controllers  behave like threads ?

Comment: @kitmir, sorry, I'm not sure I completely understand about "behave like threads". That's simply controller, that will say, which part/percent of test-threads (virtual users) will be executed along scenario you want. So for 10 threads @ 10 loops (10*10=100 executions) you'll get in accordance with your schema 10 SignUp executions, 40 - Login, etc.