# How to make in JMeter test that will make 100 requests on one site,and every fifth on another one?

Tags: automated-tests, jmeter, performance-testing

How can I create a test in JMETER that will:

- make 100 request in total, but make
- every 4th request to site A and
- every 5th request to site B

Answer (score 3):

1) You can possibly use set of [Throughput Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) - but they will work properly only in loop (as "children" of Loop Controller e.g.).

You can try to use something like below e.g.:

```
. . .
    Loop Controller
    Loop Count = 100
        Throughput Controller
        Percent Execution
        Throughput = 80.0
            HTTP Request Sampler
            Request to 1st site
        Throughput Controller
        Percent Execution
        Throughput = 20.0
            HTTP Request Sampler
            Request to 2nd site
. . .
```

Look into these for details:

- [Purpose of Throughput Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379033/purpose-of-throughput-controller)
- [Jmeter - weighted random values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481867/jmeter-weighted-random-values)
- [How throughput controller work?](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/How-throughput-controller-work-td3328412.html)

2) Another construction can be implemented only using Loop Controllers e.g.:

```
. . .
    Loop Controller
    Loop Count = 20
        Loop Controller
        Loop Count = 4
            HTTP Request Sampler
            Request to 1st site
        HTTP Request Sampler
        Request to 2nd site
. . .
```